# Guarda del bucle

Tags: java, while, bluej

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en Java sobre bucles while y no entiendo por qué en la solución la guarda del bucle while utiliza "!cond". Si pueden ayudarme lo agradecería. El enunciado es el siguiente:

Dado a un array de enteros, comprobar si hay tres números consecutivos en tres posiciones consecutivas del array; si es el caso, deberá devolver la posición en la que empieza la secuencia, o -1 si no existe.

La solución del ejercicio es:

```
/** Devuelve el índice en donde comienza
* la primera secuencia de tres valores
* seguidos, -1 si no existe */
public static int secTres(int[] a) {
    boolean cond = false;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < a.length - 2 && !cond) {
        if (a[i + 1] == a[i] + 1 &&
        a[i + 2] == a[i + 1] + 1) {
        cond = true;
        } else { i++; }
    }
    if (cond) { return i; }
    else { return -1; }
}
```

Comment: !cond es negar la variable cond... como es una variable booleana, entonces va a salir del bucle cuando sea true.. por que la negacion de true es false... es porque ya encontro el caso que buscaba....

Comment: Hola @usuario de nombre, podrias decirnos si las respuestas dadas te resultaron utiles y marcar como aceptada la q hayas entendido y darle un voto tambien si lo deseas, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El símbolo **!** es un **operador unario** de negación lógica, el cual niega el valor de una expresión booleana. Este operador cambia el valor de **True** a **False**, y de **False** a **True**.

Por otra parte la **instrucción while** ejecuta un bloque de instrucciones mientras que la expresión del **while** sea **True**.

Ahora bien, en tu ejemplo, tienes algo como esto:

```
boolean cond = false;

while (!cond) 
{
   //Código
}
```

Tu duda radica en que si la **variable cond** se inicializa en **False**, cuando se niega en el **ciclo while** debería ser **True**, pero realmente no es así y no tiene nada que ver una cosa con la otra.

La instrucción:

```
while (cond)
```

Se traduce al español como "mientras la **variable cond** sea **True** haz algo" y digamos que es una especie de "acortación" de la sintaxis:

```
while (cond == true)
```

Como ves de la primera forma escribes menos palabras.

La instrucción:

```
while (!cond)
```

Se traduce al español como "mientras el valor de la **variable cond** sea **False** haz algo", y su equivalente es:

```
while (cond == false)
```

Todo esto son recursos que ofrecen los lenguajes de programación para que los programadores escribamos menos, a ti te toca escoger cuál de las dos formas te gusta más y emplearla, es cuestión de gustos, si la forma corta te confunde pues usa la forma larga.

Te recomiendo que investigues en **Internet** sobre el término **sugar syntax** o **azúcar sintáctico**, básicamente consiste en lo que te expliqué arriba, es decir escribir código utilizando la menor cantidad de palabras.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ya se me han aclarado las dudas. Además, gracias por decirme que se llama "sugar syntax" porque estuve un buen rato tratando de buscar la solución en Google y no sabía qué poner.

Comment: @usuariodenombre que bueno que te sirvió la respuesta, podrías por favor marcarla como aceptada, gracias

Comment: Ya está, lo siento soy nuevo en Stackoverflow y aún estoy tratando de aclararme.

Answer (score 0):

1. Si `a[i + 1] == a[i] + 1 && a[i + 2] == a[i + 1] + 1` es verdadero, entonces `cond` se cambia a verdadero.
2. En el while una de las condiciones es que `cond` sea falso, entonces si se cumple el punto 1, el while ya no cumple y continúa al if en donde retorna el índice del array.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente, si quitamos ese !cond del while el método seguiría funcionando correctamente. El motivo por el que está ese !cond en el while es para evitar realizar más operaciones de la cuenta.

De primeras tienes un booleano a false. Si se cumple la condición del if dentro del while, ese booleano pasa a ser true indicando que has encontrado el número, por lo que no es necesario seguir iterando. Por eso forma parte de la condición del while. Entonces pasa al último if para validar si la condición se ha cumplido y devolver el número.

Comment: Claro, lo que no entiendo es por qué entra en el while ya que cond = false, por lo tanto !cond = true, y por ende la guarda debería evaluarse a false y no entrar. Quiero decir, tal y como yo lo veo la guarda que usaría sería  "while (i < a.length - 2 && cond)", ya que en ninguna línea anterior cambio el valor de cond = true , o cond = !cond.

Comment: El while tiene dos condiciones.


1o, el tamaño de a frente al contador
2o que el boloean sea false (puesto que ! invierte el valor del boolen)

Si las dos condiciones son true (el contador es menor que la longitud del array y que el boleano sea false) entra dentro. Una vez dentro, si es propicio, el valor del boleano pasa a ser true, entonces no se cumple la condición del while porque espera un false, entonces no itera más y pasa al return

Comment: Como tu has dicho, si antes del while analizamos cond = false. Si de aquí sacamos un if (cond) o (cond = true) no entrará en el if puesto que es false, pero si en la condición del if pusiéramos (!cond) o (cond=false) entonces entraría, porque estamos comprobando que el boleano es false.


espero haber sido más claro